# Difference between Broadcast and Multicast code in java

Tags: java, sockets

I need to send `UDP Broadcast` in the network. But I am getting confused. What I know is broadcast is not address specific and Multicast is group (Address) specific.

So, I am using `DatagramSocket` for sending and receiving `DatagramPackets` from the network.

What code I am writing is:

```
public class ComputerSender implements Runnable
{
    MulticastSocket socket;
    DatagramPacket packet;
    String command;
    public ComputerSender(String MAC)
    {
        try
        {
            socket = new MulticastSocket();
            JSONManager json = new JSONManager(MAC, WifiConstants.COMPUTER_NET_SCAN);
            json.setRecvMAC(WifiConstants.COMPUTER_NETWORK_ADDR);
            InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(WifiConstants.COMPUTER_NETWORK_ADDR);
            command="Hello";
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.v("Exception:","Computer Constructor Error: "+e.toString());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println(command);
            packet=new DatagramPacket(command.getBytes(),command.getBytes().length,InetAddress.getByName(WifiConstants.COMPUTER_NETWORK_ADDR), WifiConstants.COMPUTER_SEND_PORT);
            socket.setTimeToLive(100);
            socket.send(packet);
            System.out.println("Packet Sent");
            Thread.sleep(200);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.v("Packet Sending Error: ","Computer Error: "+e.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            socket.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I am not able to predict the above code is for Broadcast or Multicast. If Broadcast then what changes I need to make it for Multicast. and if Multicast then what changes I need to bring for Boradcast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the value of `WifiConstants.COMPUTER_NETWORK_ADDR`.

For broadcast, it needs to be the broadcast address of your network segment.  For example, if your IP address is 10.1.2.3 with a subnet mask of 255.255.0.0, then 10.1.255.255 is the broadcast address.

Multicast addresses, however, use a group address in the multicast address range.

According to IANA (http://www.iana.org/assignments/multicast-addresses/multicast-addresses.xml):

> The multicast addresses are in the range
>   224.0.0.0 through 239.255.255.255.

Therefore, if the destination IP address is in that range, say 224.224.1.2, then any clients listening on that multicast group address will receive your packet.

Comment: should I use DatagramSocket or Multicast Socket for broadcast,..?

Comment: DatagramSocket.  I'm not sure what would happen if you use MulticastSocket for a broadcast, but I suspect it wouldn't do anything desirable.

Comment: You can use either for sending. You must use a MulticastSocket for receiving multicasts.